# How to select an item from a listbox in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've a list of data,
Each row will show a data and will have a button, when i click the data shown i want give some data to the previous page and when i click the button in the same row i want to send that same  data to next page.

My Xaml code,

```
<ListBox x:Name="List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="612" Margin="6,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="443" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="420" Height="50">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Width="400" Height="44" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Button x:Name="DetailButton" Height="44" Width="20" Content=">" FontWeight="Bold" Click="DetailButton_Click_1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and the code for **List_SelectionChanged_1** event handler is,

```
private void List_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Display selectedItemData = (sender as ListBox).SelectedValue as Display;            
        NavigationService.Navigate("/Page1.xaml",selectedItemData);
    }
```

and my **DetailButton_Click_1** event handler is,

```
private void DetailButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Display selectedItemData = (sender as ListBox).SelectedValue as Display;
        NavigationService.Navigate("/page3.xaml", selectedItemData);
    }
```

Things work fine for *List_SelectionChanged_1*, but i get an exception while executing

```
Display selectedItemData = (sender as ListBox).SelectedValue as Display;
```

of the **DetailButton_Click_1** , i get an exception a null exception,

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ExpenseApp.DLL but was not handled in user code
```

What should i do make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is that the sender of the button click event is the button, not the ListBox.

Also note that clicking the button on your data template will not necessarily select that item in the list.  Try to grab the clicked item's data context and use that instead of .SelectedItem

```
private void DetailButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedUIElement =  sender as Button;
    if (null == clickedUIElement) { Return; }
    Display selectedItemData = clickedUIElement.DataContext as Display;
    if(null != selectedItemData)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate("/page3.xaml", selectedItemData);
    }
}
```

Your code, as it stands, will have a null reference since you can't cast a Button as a ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

try verify if the selectvalue is null before execute the code:

```
 private void DetailButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        If ((sender as ListBox).SelectedValue != null){
             Display selectedItemData = (sender as ListBox).SelectedValue as Display;
             NavigationService.Navigate("/page3.xaml", selectedItemData);
        }
    }
```